# Testing installation script on Linux

Tags: bash, apt-get

I'm writing a Bash script that sets up a Drupal development environment for people using Ubuntu. To test this out I've installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu in [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) and am constantly using the snapshot feature to get back my fresh install after every run of the script.

Currently however my script is re-downloading all the packages that need to be installed every time I run the script. Is there a way I can get `apt-get` to install these packages from local storage?

Perhaps downloading them, but not installing them at once. Taking a snapshot then, and then usage of `apt-get` that will use the local packages that were downloaded.

How would I go about doing this? Is there perhaps some `apt-get` magic that will do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-get --download-only install` should do the trick.

Then make the snapshot, then run `apt-get install` again without --download-only.